# How do I open the quickfix window instead of displaying grep results?

Tags: vim

I am searching through a large codebase and find `vimgrep` unusably slow, so I'm using `:grep` from within vim, which displays a list of files, then says `Press ENTER or type command to continue`.

After I press `Enter` I can then type `:copen` to get to the list of results. But I'm wondering if I could automate this process? Adding the `-q` flag to `grep` seems to have the effect of causing grep to do nothing and then `copen` to be blank, which, unless I'm doing something wrong here, isn't really desirable.

I am using vim 7.4

Answer (score 3):

You could define such a command :

```
command! -bar -nargs=1 Grep silent grep <q-args> | redraw! | cw
```

This will allow you to call it like `Grep pattern`, and `:cw` which opens the quickfix list only if it isn't empty.

Comment: When I run `Grep "pattern"` I just get `E471: Argument required`

Comment: You don't need quotes, if you must, then use single quotes `'`

Comment: I like how this skips the "Press ENTER" message.  For some reason, it didn't like the `|`s here (I got `E488: Trailing characters:  cw /dev/null`), so I had to tweak it: `command! -bar -nargs=1 Grep silent execute "grep <args>" | redraw! | cw`  The reason may be that my `grepprg=grep -n $* /dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

Use an autocommand. Here is the one [suggested by Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive#faq) for `:Ggrep`. It will work for your case as well:

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost *grep* cwindow
```

For more information see:

```
:h :au
:h QuickFixCmdPost
:h :cwindow
```